# Filtering array doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a big array with about 50.000 elements and need to filter out those elements that have the value `null`. The code looks like this:

```
const test2 = test.filter(({latitude, longitude}) => latitude != null 
&& longitude != null);

function functionWithaName(test2) {…};
```

The array looks similar to this:

```
test = 
[{"city":"NYC","longitude":-73.935242,"latitude":40.730610},
{"city":"NYC","longitude":-74.044502,"latitude":40.689247}]
```

The new filtered array should be stored in test2 but the filter doesn't seem to work …
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to filter an array of objects?

Comment: I suppose you're filtering an array. Can you post your sample data?

Comment: How doesn't it work? Code looks OK.